# Sublime Text SFTP and gulpfile issues

Tags: javascript, gulp, sftp

I have the plugin SFTP installed in Sublime Text.
I then have a gulpfile that compiles my scss files to css.

When i save the scss file i can see the changes in the css file, but SFTP does not notice that the css file is getting "saved" when i compile so it won't upload it.

Have been searching a little, and someone said to do SFTP: Monitor File(Upload on External Save) but that did not work.

Does anyone have a solution for this?
My gulpfile is pretty simple at the moment.

```
//gulfile.js
//

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');



// Style Paths
var sassFiles = '__src/scss/**/*.scss',
    cssDest = 'wp-content/themes/gdesign/';


gulp.task('styles', function() {
    gulp.src(sassFiles)
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(cssDest))
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(sassFiles, ['styles']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue @rubylearner. The work around I have for now is to use 'gulp-sftp' and also 'run-sequence'.

So I watch for changes to my SASS files, then run a 'sequence' of compile css, upload with sftp, and then I also am using 'browserSync' to reload my page after the changes.

This is the task I run:

```
gulp.task('watch', function (){
    gulp.watch('sass/**/*.scss', function(){ runSequence('sass','sftp',reload) });
})
```

Comment: How you start the gulp watch task? I'm wondering if there is an automatic way to start it as soon as i open a project.

Answer (score 0):

I have pretty similar setup. The Sublime SFTP file monitor should work fine as long as you keep the monitored css file open.